# How to read json file from directory and display in app

Tags: react-native, path, react-native-flatlist, readfile, writefile

I have been trying to download and read **JSON** file from my application directory (which if obviously an array of objects) to map and display inside my app.

note-: downloading part is successful also I can read the file but it returns content of file as it is,I cannot map over its content. Is there a way I can do so..

```
RNFS.readFile(myfilePath, 'ascii')
.then(fileData => {
 console.log(fileData);
 })
.catch(err => {
console.log(err.message, err.code);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert json string to JavaScript value.

```
RNFS.readFile(myfilePath, 'ascii')
  .then(fileData => {
    console.log(fileData);
    const data = JSON.parse(fileData)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message, err.code);
  });
```